# Create component with CSS class depending on props given

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

Is there a way in Vue.js to create a component that is containing CSS **class** scoped on which some values are given as parameters (props) before his creation.

Like:

```html
<BeautifulBar :colorSelected="red" :colorDefault="blue", :animDuration="10.0s"></BeautifulBar
```

And in the component itself:

```html
<template>
   <div :class="'bar ' + (selected ? 'selected animated' : 'default')" @click="select()">The Bar</div>
</template>
<script>
   export default{
   data: function () { return { selected: false } },
   props: {
      colorSelected : {default: "orange", type: String},
      colorDefault: {default: "orange", type: String},
      animDuration: {default: "4.0s", type: String},
   },
   method: {
    select: function() { this.selected = !this.selected;}
   }
   }
</script>
/* HERE */
<style scoped>
   selected: {
   color: red,
   background-color: var(this.colorSelected)
   }
   default: {
   color: black,
   background-color: var(this.colorDefault)
   }
   animate:{
   -webkit-transition: var(animDuration) !important;
   -moz-transition: var() !important;
   -o-transition: var() !important;
   transition: var() !important;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed doing it like this (showing a progress bar looping animation, you can pass the animation time as props):

```html
<template>
  <div class="progress" :style="`height: ${height}rem;`">
    <div
      :class="'progress-bar bg-success ' + 'progressAnimation'"
      role="progressbar"
      :style="`width: ${progressValue}%; --animationDuration: ${animationDurationStr};`"
      :aria-valuenow="`${progressValue}`"
      aria-valuemin="0"
      aria-valuemax="100"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script scoped>
import config from "../config";

export default {
  props: {
    animationDuration: { type: Number, default: 140 },
    height: { type: Number, default: 0.25 }
  },
  created: function() {
    config.log("------------ AutoLoopProgressBar -----------");
    config.log(
      "autoloopprogressbar",
      "Set animation duration to " + this.animationDurationStr
    );
  },
  mounted: function() {
    config.log("autoloopprogressbar", "Setup timer");
    setInterval(() => {
      this.reset();
    }, this.animationDuration * 1000);
    this.reset();
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      progressValue: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    animationDurationStr: function() {
      return this.animationDuration + ".0s";
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reset: function() {
      let tmp = this.animationDuration;
      this.animationDuration = 0;
      this.progressValue = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.animationDuration = tmp;
        this.progressValue = 100;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.progressAnimation {
  --animationDuration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: var(--animationDuration) linear !important;
  -moz-transition: var(--animationDuration) linear !important;
  -o-transition: var(--animationDuration) linear !important;
  transition: var(--animationDuration) linear !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using computed function for class?

```
computed:{
    classObject:function(){
        return {
            'selected': this.selected,
            'animated': this.selected,
            'default': !this.selected
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
<div :class="classObject">
your template
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for, I'm speaking about creating a css class that is depending of the props given during the instantiation process.